# Why is cheese considered to be unhealthy even though one slice of processed cheese averages at around 50-60cals?

Tags: weight-loss, nutrition, food

One reason I can think of is the fact that for the cheese slices that I occasionally buy, 41/50 cals come from fat. But for an overweight person (me) trying to lose weight and eating healthy+working out, can half a slice of processed cheese slow down results?

Comment: First of all, "unhealthy" is largely subjective. Who is telling you it's healthy or unhealthy? Secondly, the number of calories is NOT a measure of how healthy something is. Thirdly, this will probably be closed as off-topic. Not related to exercise.

Comment: Calories (based on your TDEE) are a good starting point for determining a healthy nutrition plan, but they are only a starting point. Going a step further, determining an optimal macronutrient balance is going to help you bring your nutrition even closer to ideal. After that, you’ll want to ensure that you are getting an appropriate amount of all your micronutrients. As Alec mentioned, “healthy” is a subjective term, but looking at calories, macronutrients, and micronutrients will help you to determine whether or not something is healthy or beneficial for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No food is unhealthy if it fits into your macros. A slice of cheese contains approximately 113g calories of which 9g are fats and 7g are proteins. Since you're an overweight person, you don't need a lot of fats, but proteins. Considering a slice of cheese provides more fats than proteins, it will hinder your long-term goals.

A far better substitution would be, say, 3 egg whites. It would provide you with 51 calories, has negligible fats, and 11g of proteins. This will provide you with healthy proteins that will keep your fat gains to a minimum while building muscle effectively.

Comment: Why should fats be kept to a minimum? The body needs fats to function properly.

Comment: @JustSnilloc Yes, fats are mandatory for the body to function properly. However, I assume that the OP is still taking necessary fats from other foods and there is no need to further supplement it with a slice of cheese. If, in case, the OP does not have enough fats in his diet then he may eat three whole eggs instead of egg whites which consists of healthy fats and other minerals required to attain the daily recommendation of his individual fat intake.